# How to disable socket.io-client debug messages in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image: Debug Message]

How to disable socket.io-client debug messages in react native

const socket = SocketIOClient('https://vast-rules-jam-103-215-227-221.loca.lt', {
transports: ['websocket'],
query: {
callerId,
},
});